# scheduling data is not being saved JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This code I amusing. But data is not being save but hello is printing please guide me.

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    TestRepository testRepo;

    final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestService.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        process();
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    }

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    log.info("Exception while starting schedular :" + exception);
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void process() {
        Test t=new Test(); 
        t.id=null;
        t.name="Lokesh";
        testRepo.save(t);
       log.info("hello");
    }
}
```

Problem is that Lokesh is not saving for table test ....

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP. Which means that only method calls INTO the object will be touched by AOP. You are doing an internal method call, so basically you `@Transactional` is ignored. Without a transaction, nothing is going to be saved. Also why on earth the ugly hack in an init method, which makes things even worse because it in't even guaranteed that proxies already have bean created. Basically your code is wrong on multiple levels.

Comment: Please  write TestRepository.class.

Comment: TestRepository  .....................................................................................................................................................             
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test,Long>{

 Test findById(Long id);
 List<Test> findAll();
}